# How to assign values to has_and_belongs_to_many association of existing models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: Recipient and List. Both have has_and_belongs_to_many association. If I wanted to create a List with new recipients, `List.find(x).recipients.new` works well.

However what I want now is to assign existing recipients to a new List. How would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List.find(x).recipients << Recipient.find(y)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically,you could each recipients and set its list to your new list.

```
Recipients.each do |recipient|
    recipient.list = list
end
```

but if your recipients is large,the way is too stupid. you could have them done at a same time like code below:

```
Recipient.update_all(updates, conditions = nil, options = {})
```